# HTML/CSS: Make text overlay but keep video responsive to mouse events (Elementor)

Tags: html, css, elementor

we're kinda new to this whole webpage coding stuff and are currently working on setting up our own wordpress page with custom html/css via wordpress/elementor (but still in the free version, not pro).

We made a video autoplay and react to hover mouse events and mouseclicks, but as we tried to put a text overlay over the videobox with a .overlay class, the overlay class would cover the whole video and the actual video wouldn't react to our mouse. The goal is to display the text over the video, whilst the video itself keeps playing and pausing when hovering over it.

We're using the HTML function of the Elementor plugin.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Here is what we got so far (and yes, we're newbs when it comes to coding, sorry for the messy code I guess):

```
<style>
    .Maus {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 22pt;
        line-height: 22pt;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class=Maus>
    <div onmousedown="openInNewTab('https://private.com/video/');">

        <video loop="this.play()" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause();">
    
        <source src="https://private.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        
         <div class=overlay>
                <p>
                lorem ipsum
                </p>
             
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function openInNewTab(url) 
     {
        window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
        }
</script>
```

here is a screenshot of it:

[videofile in elementor widget with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5BBD.png)

Tried messing around with the z-index, but failed as elements were overlapping the text so it was behind the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `pointer-events: none;` to make an element let mouse actions "go through it" (to the element behind it)

Comment: One question, we're trying to make the text "disappear" after hovering for a few seconds over it, wouldn't this prevent us from doing so? Do you have a tip?

Comment: it depends how you make it disappear. If by CSS transition, you can use a selector like `.Maus:hover .overlay { transition: ... }`

Comment: We tried to do it like that, problem is, `.Maus` class will make both, the video and text disappear, and we tried to add a `.overlay:hover ` function, but the `pointer-events: none;` inside the `.overlay` class is preventing us from doing so

Comment: well, you can't have both...

Comment: but you could create a "fadeout" for the overlay either some seconds after loading or after starting the video, using JS

Comment: shame, we tried to make it look a litte like this one [Immigrant.studio](https://www.immigrant.studio/) , there it seems to work, but we'll keep messing around, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the property I think it will help you:

```
pointer-events: none;
```